# How to replace values in one line by NA in R?

Tags: r

I have a text file:

```
df=read.table("E:\\value.txt", sep="\t")
df
  k    jh   fg          
1  208  0.15 0.17  
2  304  0.00 0.08
```

Now I want to replace unwanted values in `k` with `NA`

```
df$k[df$k >= 500 ]=NA
```

There is no problem with that but I would like to replace all corresponding values (in the same line in `jh and fg` ) by `NA` as well!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to imagine this wasn't illustrated in some prior answer (but I did search):

```
is.na(df1[df1$k >300, ] ) <- TRUE
```

The fact that this was acceptable code for a dataframe object and `"[.data.frame"` suggests to me that it might also work for the more complex case where the column classes were more varied. There are specific `is.na<-` methods for specific classes:

```
> methods(`is.na<-`)
[1] is.na<-.default  is.na<-.discrete is.na<-.factor
```

Comment: `df1 <- df1[ !df1$k >500 , ]` Although the strange (to my way of thinking) behavior of `[.data.frame` means that you will get NA-lines for any position of df$k that holds a NA value. Use `subset` or use `& is.na(df$k)` inside the "i" argument to "[".

Comment: If the rownames are in their default state you can use `rownames(df)!=2`

Comment: I have been bitten by efforts at selecting by row numbers when the test is logical. You only get 0,' and 1's so you may get nothing only the first line. Try: ` df2[!2,]`  .... return empty dataframe. This succeeds `df2[!seq(nrow(df2)) %in% 2,]`

Comment: (You needed to use it as the "i"-argument to "[.data.frame".) The SO interface it telling me this is turnign into a chat so and I'm going to go back to my regular job.